# creating a clickable php calendar

Tags: php, calendar

I am making a calendar in php. please help me because what I want to happen is that it should look like a real calendar and each day should be clickable and in that way, I can add info/note or a reminder to that day. I dont how to start with it. thanks

Comment: I think starting with writing some code would be good! (Here I give you the first line: `<?php`)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should start with reading some documentation about date() function. Than You will need some knowledge of `Javascript` and `Ajax` to add notes and also UI technologies like bootstrap will be useful to make responsive design.
1) Date() function and correct output of calendar from server.
2) Javascript/Ajax functions to add notes without refresh.
3) Markup

Comment: You can make my answer green, if it helps a lot :).